# How to calculate current row value based on the data of last 56 days

Tags: sql, teradata

```
country_id  store_id    item_id wh_id   date    fg
23  9,478   1,007,047   9,074   3/5/2018    0
23  9,478   1,007,047   9,074   3/7/2018    0
23  9,478   1,007,047   9,074   3/10/2018   0
23  9,478   1,007,047   9,074   3/11/2018   1
23  9,478   1,007,047   9,074   3/17/2018   0
23  9,478   1,007,047   9,074   3/18/2018   1
23  9,478   1,007,047   9,074   3/27/2018   0
23  9,478   1,007,047   9,074   3/28/2018   0
23  9,478   1,007,047   9,074   3/29/2018   0
```

This is the source data, target calculation rule is
When  `fg=1` and there is at least 1 record with `fg=0` in last 56 days (all dates are not available in source) then it will set to 1 else 0.

I tried to do it with OLAP functions but OLAP function works row wise  and i need data dates wise.

Comment: Hey Kiran, to avoid the downvotes, you'd have to provide the source data in a way that is immediately useable, like that:
data = data.frame(country_id=c(23,23),store_id=c(9478,9478),item_id=c(1007047,1007047),wh_id=c(9074,9074),date=c("3/5/2018","3/7/2018"),fg=c(0,0))

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select (case when fg = 1 and
                  max(case when fg = 0 then date end) over
                     (partition by country_id, store_id, item_id, wh_id
                      order by date
                      rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                     ) >= date + interval '-56' day
             then 1 else 0
         end) as target
```

I am guessing what the partitioning columns are.  The logic is simple . . . calculate the most recent date with `fg = 0` and use that for the comparison.

Comment: Teradata doesn't support `range` (probably because they never found an efficient parallel algorithm to implement it).

Comment: well, a range of 5 days or hours could be millions/billions of rows and Teradata already limits ROWS to 4096 due to performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This should return what you want:

```
SELECT tab.*
  ,CASE WHEN fg = 1
             -- latest row with "fg = 0"
         AND Last_Value(CASE WHEN fg = 0 THEN datecol END IGNORE NULLS)
             Over (PARTITION BY store_id           -- or whatever you need
                   ORDER BY datecol) > datecol-56  -- maybe ">= datecol-56"
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
   END
FROM tab
```